# Difference between Co-curricular activities and Extra-curricular activities and Hobby

Tags: meaning, differences

What is the difference between these fields in a resume primarily Co-curricular activities and Extra-curricular activities ; Extra-curricular activities and Hobby.

I wan to know The meaning and usage mostly pertaining to a resume and as to what things are to be filled in each of these fields and how (much) do they differ from each other

//...
Filling a resume recently i got confused as to the real meaning of these 3 fields.
The internet has very very vague answers to each of them with each source saying something different from the other.

P.S. my first post. I dont really know where this questions belongs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Hobby*** is totally different from '***Co-curricular activities***' and '***Extra-curricular activities***'.

***Hobby*** grows naturally within the mind of a person. It totally depends on his likes and dislikes, his curiosity, his calling, his inclination towards that particular activity. For example if a boy / girl likes to collect stamps, badges, bottle crowns, tickets, or even chocolate wrappers, he does it because he likes to do it. He receives no external pressure for doing so.

'***Curriculum***' refers to the course of study which is followed in a particular school or by a board. Any activity beyond the limit of the curriculum may be referred to as '***Co-curricular activities***' and '***Extra-curricular activities***'.

'***Co-curricular activities***' and '***Extra-curricular activities***' are imposed externally, unlike '***hobby***'. These two terms are quite similar in nature. '***Co-curricular activities***' refer to those activities which complement learning experience of the students in the schools. These activities are connected with academic and are organised or designed to help the students have a better understanding of his course. '***Extra-curricular activities***' (or sometimes referred to as Extra Academic Activity) refer to those activities which are totally outside the realm of normal curriculum, but are essential for the all round development of the students. While a quiz, mental mathematics, 'spell bee', etc, are '***Co-curricular activities***', sports, gym, swimming, athletics, etc, are '***Extra-curricular activities***' .

Comment: I would say that in the U.S., any distinction between *co-curricular* and *extracurricular* has long been meaningless— there is almost no activity defined by one school as co-curricular that some other school will not define as extracurricular, and vice-versa. A web search will turn up schools that classify sports, student government, art, and community service as one or the other, but more to the point, most institutions seem use one or the other as the *universal* term, especially the more "modern" *co-curricular*.